# How do I setup Yii for multiple subdomains so the protected folder sits outside the document root for each subdomain

Tags: php, oop, ubuntu, yii, lamp

I have decided to start coding using OOP and a PHP framework. I have successfully installed Yii on a development server and created a webapp. Now, I would like to move the protected folder to a level outside the document root for security reasons. My question is how to do this when there are multiple subdomains that I will also be using Yii with.

I have experience with PHP, but not in an OOP style and this is my initial step into OOP and frameworks. Also, I have a LAMP system installed on Ubuntu for development.

My path structure is below, which matches the production server. I have a top level site and multiple other top level sites and subdomain sites for one of the top level sites.

top level site - /home/mark/public_html/{website one files}
top level site - /home/mark/public_html/website-two.com/{website-two files}
top level site - /home/mark/public_html/website-three.com/{website-three files}
my sub domains - /home/mark/public_html/sub1.website-three.com/{sub files}
my sub domains - /home/mark/public_html/sub2.website-three.com/{sub2 files}
my sub domains - /home/mark/public_html/sub3.website-three.com/{sub3 files}

I have Yii installed at: /home/mark/Yii

I have created a webapp at: /home/mark/public_html/sub1.website-three.com and access the Yii webapp locally at http://sub1.website-three/ ....I don't use http://localhost since I have virtual hosts and sub domains. All of this works, and will be creating more webapps at other subdomains under website-three.

Can I rename the protected folder to sub_protected and place it at /home/mark, and then for my next webapp, name the protected folder sub2_protected and so on? Should I use a different path structure??? Also, I believe I will need to edit the protected/config/main.php for each site to reflect the changes???

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Can't wait to get this configured so I can dive further into Yii ...looks very intriguing so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name the protected folder whatever you want and put it anywhere on your file system that your webserver user has access to, so, yes /home/mark/sub*n*_protected scheme would work.

However, particularly if your sites are similar and have any shared code, it might be more efficient to use one protected folder and set up an array of urlManager rules in your main config file and load the appropriate rules base on the host name. You can then have dedicated controllers for each host as well as views directories. I've often done this for mobile versions where you can also add mobile detection to the mix.

If the sites are distinct, using separate protected directories might sense as well. E.g., I'll use a separate protected directory for admin tools based on the Gii-generated scaffolding.

If the sites are very similar, you also might want to check out Themes:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming

Comment: Thanks, I did get the protected folder moved and renamed, but now thinking about what you said. The sites are very similar ...same data structure, same layout, just different names and different colors/images, etc. If I can get them all to share the same protected folder and then use themes, that sounds like the way to go. What about sharing the same db? Does that add any issues to sharing the protected folder or with the themes?

Comment: No, I don't see any issues with sharing the same DB. If for some reason you didn't want to, you can always use the same technique outlined above for loading different rules for the urlManager and load different DB settings, even use different table prefixes for different sites/hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can place protected folder under the document root.
Just use for website one next code in your config:

```
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
```

and your `protected` folder will be looked at

```
/home/mark/protected
```

Comment: Thanks, I did get the protected folder moved and renamed and the config changed to represent the change. All is working ...but now thinking of the the themes and db, and best way to handle those. This page also helped ...http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/116/how-to-set-up-directory-structures-for-multiple-yii-project-support/